# about the RTL view in xilinx

Tags: vhdl

Actually in my vhdl project i have included the blocks for clock generator,LSFR(data generator),IQ mapper,polyphase . Out of all these blocks the block polyphase block is  fully missing in the rtl view. IS it the problem in the coding technique . Actually I am using the interpolation factor 32. So i have created 32 subfilters as blocks in the component polyphase. If there any problem in this below code please reply immediately.

this is code for polyphase component and the componenets inside polyphase are subfilters

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED.ALL;

---- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
---- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity polyphase is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;

            clk_120mbps: in std_logic;
           reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           din : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0);
           ifiltout : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(23 downto 0)
              );
end polyphase;

architecture Behavioral of polyphase is

component subfilta
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;

component subfiltb
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
----                
component subfiltc
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
----                
component subfiltd
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
----
component subfilte
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;  
--
component subfiltf
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;              
----                
component subfiltg
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
--              
component subfilth
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
----                
component subfilti
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;

                component subfiltj
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;

component subfiltk
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
----                
component subfiltl
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
----                
component subfiltm
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
------
component subfiltn
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;  
--
component subfilto
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;              
--              
component subfiltp
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;

component subfiltq
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;

component subfiltr
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
----                
component subfilts
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
----                
component subfiltt
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
----
component subfiltu
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;  
--
component subfiltv
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;              
--              
component subfiltw
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
--              
component subfiltx
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
----                
component subfilty
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;

                component subfiltz
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;

component subfiltaa
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
----                
component subfiltbb
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
----                
component subfiltcc
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;
----
component subfiltdd
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;  
--
component subfiltee
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;              
--              
component subfiltff
        port( dout:out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              clk:in std_logic;

                reset:in std_logic;
                din:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
                end component;              


signal ifilterout0,ifilterout1,ifilterout2,ifilterout3:STD_LOGIC_vector(23 downto 0):=(others =>'0');
signal ifilterout4,ifilterout5,ifilterout6,ifilterout7:STD_LOGIC_vector(23 downto 0):=(others =>'0');

signal ifilterout8,ifilterout9,ifilterout10,ifilterout11:STD_LOGIC_vector(23 downto 0):=(others =>'0');
signal ifilterout12,ifilterout13,ifilterout14,ifilterout15:STD_LOGIC_vector(23 downto 0):=(others =>'0');

signal ifilterout16,ifilterout17,ifilterout18,ifilterout19:STD_LOGIC_vector(23 downto 0):=(others =>'0');
signal ifilterout20,ifilterout21,ifilterout22,ifilterout23:STD_LOGIC_vector(23 downto 0):=(others =>'0');

signal ifilterout24,ifilterout25,ifilterout26,ifilterout27:STD_LOGIC_vector(23 downto 0):=(others =>'0');
signal ifilterout28,ifilterout29,ifilterout30,ifilterout31:STD_LOGIC_vector(23 downto 0):=(others =>'0');
--

begin
subfilt0a: subfilta port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout0);
subfilt0b: subfiltb port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout1);
subfilt0c: subfiltc port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout2);
subfilt0d: subfiltd port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout3);
subfilt0e: subfilte port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout4);
subfilt0f: subfiltf port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout5);
subfilt0g: subfiltg port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout6);
subfilt0h: subfilth port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout7);

subfilt0i: subfilti port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout8);
subfilt0j: subfiltj port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout9);
subfilt0k: subfiltk port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout10);
subfilt0l: subfiltl port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout11);
subfilt0m: subfiltm port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout12);
subfilt0n: subfiltn port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout13);
subfilt0o: subfilto port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout14);
subfilt0p: subfiltp port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout15);

subfilt0q: subfiltq port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout16);
subfilt0r: subfiltr port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout17);
subfilt0s: subfilts port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout18);
subfilt0t: subfiltt port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout19);
subfilt0u: subfiltu port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout20);
subfilt0v: subfiltv port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout21);
subfilt0w: subfiltw port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout22);
subfilt0x: subfiltx port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout23);

subfilt0y: subfilty port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout24);
subfilt0z: subfiltz port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout25);
subfilt0aa: subfiltaa port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout26);
subfilt0bb: subfiltbb port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout27);
subfilt0cc: subfiltcc port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout28);
subfilt0dd: subfiltdd port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout29);
subfilt0ee: subfiltee port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout30);
subfilt0ff: subfiltff port map( Reset=> Reset, Clk=>Clk, din => din, dout => ifilterout31);

--
P20:PROCESS(clk_120mbps,RESET)
 VARIABLE CNT:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 DOWNTO 0):="000000";
 BEGIN


 IF RESET='0' THEN
    CNT:="000000";
    ifiltout <=(others =>'0');
     ELSIF clk_120mbps='1' AND clk_120mbps'EVENT THEN
     CNT := CNT +1;
     CASE CNT IS 
     WHEN   "000001"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout0;
     WHEN   "000010"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout1;
     WHEN   "000011"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout2;
     WHEN   "000100"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout3;
     WHEN   "000101"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout4;
     WHEN   "000110"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout5;

     WHEN   "000111"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout6;
     WHEN   "001000"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout7;

     WHEN   "001001"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout8;
     WHEN   "001010"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout9;
     WHEN   "001011"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout10;
     WHEN   "001100"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout11;
     WHEN   "001101"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout12;
     WHEN   "001110"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout13;
----     
     WHEN   "001111"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout14;
     WHEN   "010000"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout15;

     WHEN   "010001"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout16;
     WHEN   "010010"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout17;
     WHEN   "010011"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout18;
     WHEN   "010100"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout19;
     WHEN   "010101"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout20;
     WHEN   "010110"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout21;

     WHEN   "010111"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout22;
     WHEN   "011000"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout23;

     WHEN   "011001"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout24;
     WHEN   "011010"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout25;
     WHEN   "011011"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout26;
     WHEN   "011100"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout27;
     WHEN   "011101"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout28;
     WHEN   "011110"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout29;

     WHEN   "011111"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout30;
     WHEN   "100000"=> ifiltout <=ifilterout31;
--   

--   
                    CNT := "000000";

     WHEN OTHERS => ifiltout <="000000000000000000000000";
     END CASE;
     --CNT <= CNT +1;
     END IF;
 END PROCESS P20;



end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a coding problem. If a mistake like an unconnected output means the synthesis tool can optimise a block away to nothing, it will do so, and then there is nothing to display in the RTL viewer.

The synthesis report (.syr) contains a lot of information about trimming  unused logic. Read through it.

But first : did this design work correctly in simulation? Most likely not, and you would be best to find the faults in simulation before moving to synthesis.

And finally : using an array of ifilterout words and a "for ... generate" statement would make this code about 30x shorter and much easier to maintain.